# How to tell `git log --[num|short]stat` to count empty lines

Tags: git, diff

## General question

How can I tell `git`, that it should also count empty lines in a diff, when using `git log --stat`?

## Code example

```
git clone https://github.com/voldemort/voldemort.git
cd voldemort
git log --numstat -n 1 c21ad76 contrib/hadoop-store-builder/src/java/voldemort/store/readonly/mr/HadoopStoreBuilderReducer.java
git show c21ad76 -- contrib/hadoop-store-builder/src/java/voldemort/store/readonly/mr/HadoopStoreBuilderReducer.java
```

## More details

In the given example `git log --numstat` claims for commit `c21ad76`, that file `HadoopStoreBuilderReducer.java` has *25 added* and *22 removed* lines . If you have a closer look at the diff output (`git show`) of that file you can see, that there are actually *30 added* and *25 removed* lines, which make it different by **5 added** and **3 deleted** lines. At an even closer look, there are 5 empty lines inside the added lines hunk and 4 empty lines in the deleted lines hunk.

This behavior is the same with `git log --shortstat` or `git log --stat`.

It appears to me, that all empty lines, which are inside an hunk are **not** counted by `git log --numstat`.

How can I calculate with `git` the number of added and removed lines per commit **including blank lines**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Context

There are several different (valid) patches for the same change. The main difference is the use of context lines. Unified diff usually uses three lines of context before and after each change. Internally git (sometimes) uses zero lines of context which can result to different changed lines.

## First solution: external tool

As @karl-bielefeldt already described, one can pipe the result of `git show` into `grep -Pc '^\+(?!\+)'` or `grep -Pc '^-(?!-)'`. There is the tool `diffstat` which does exactly that:

```
$git show c21ad76 -- contrib/hadoop-store-builder/src/java/voldemort/store/readonly/mr/HadoopStoreBuilderReducer.java | diffstat
 HadoopStoreBuilderReducer.java |   57 +++++++++++++++++++++--------------------
 1 file changed, 30 insertions(+), 27 deletions(-)
```

## Second solution: use different contexts for the patch

The output patch of git show can be configured. With the option "-Ux" for x a context can be specified.

```
$git show -U0 c21ad76 -- contrib/hadoop-store-builder/src/java/voldemort/store/readonly/mr/HadoopStoreBuilderReducer.java | diffstat
 HadoopStoreBuilderReducer.java |   47 +++++++++++++++++++++--------------------
 1 file changed, 25 insertions(+), 22 deletions(-)
```

This matches the internal `git log --numstat` because it uses a 0 context for calculating the stat. Note that this behaviour is about to change in git version 1.7.7. With that numstat uses 3 lines of context.

Answer (score 0):

I count 27 removed and 30 added.  I don't know if there's a way to do it with internal git, but this worked for me:

```
git show c21ad76 -- contrib/hadoop-store-builder/src/java/voldemort/store/readonly/mr/HadoopStoreBuilderReducer.java | grep -Pc '^\+(?!\+)'
git show c21ad76 -- contrib/hadoop-store-builder/src/java/voldemort/store/readonly/mr/HadoopStoreBuilderReducer.java | grep -Pc '^-(?!-)'
```

Comment: Well, it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but at least I can now  avoid this shortcoming of git. Thx.